# Encountering connection problems with PostgreSQL when using psycopg2 on a port that has been forwarded

Tags: python, postgresql, kubernetes

While attempting to connect to PostgreSQL using a Python script, the port forwarding encounters an error and terminates. the script i used while connecting to PostgreSQL is as follows.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import psycopg2

# PostgreSQL connection
postgres_conn = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname='consumer',
    user='postgres',
    password='postgres',
    host='localhost',
    port='5555'

)
postgres_cursor = postgres_conn.cursor()

def check_postgres_connection():
    try:
        # Sample PostgreSQL query
        postgres_cursor.execute("SELECT version();")
        result = postgres_cursor.fetchone()
        print(f"PostgreSQL Connection Successful. Sample Query Result: {result}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"PostgreSQL Connection Failed. Error: {e}")
    finally:
        # Close PostgreSQL connection
        postgres_cursor.close()
        # postgres_conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("\n")
    check_postgres_connection()
```

I am getting error like this when port forwarding terminates

```
E0117 14:56:51.730310  4476 portforward.go:409] an error occurred forwarding 5555 -> 5432: error forwarding port 5432 to pod 8c9e848be4b2d7ed8ff22e7ae9d083e99ea3d31ae4bafb813a86c913f0a86235, uid : failed to execute portforward in network namespace "/var/run/netns/cni-098ba5a6-96f0-0e6c-7456-1a7a28e6ae23": read tcp4 127.0.0.1:36974->127.0.0.1:5432: read: connection reset by peer
```

I've tried using a different library instead of pycopg2 but the error still persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the error is related to Kubernetes port forwarding, not psycopg2, and you're trying to forward local port `5555` to port `5432` on a pod, but the connection is being reset.

So try to check results of:

`kubectl port-forward pod-name 5555:5432 -n namespace`

Then, if after trying a different local port not works and the PostgreSQL pod state is running, check the pod logs:

`kubectl logs pod -n namespace`

And if not find new responses In case of there's not network policies from cluster to verify, check the postgreSQL config `pg_hba.conf` to see if there be connections restriction from certain IP addresses/ranges.

I hope that helps